# Google Dataflow job failing continuously: "Pipe broken"

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, dataflow

I've been using the same code for a long time it used to work but when I re-run our batch loader it gave error not enough disk space so I increased the disk size and ran again then I get Pipeline broken error like below

```
    (84383c8e79f9b6a1): java.io.IOException: java.io.IOException: Pipe broken
    at com.google.cloud.hadoop.util.AbstractGoogleAsyncWriteChannel.waitForCompletionAndThrowIfUploadFailed(AbstractGoogleAsyncWriteChannel.java:431)
    at com.google.cloud.hadoop.util.AbstractGoogleAsyncWriteChannel.close(AbstractGoogleAsyncWriteChannel.java:289)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.TextSink$TextFileWriter.close(TextSink.java:243)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.common.worker.WriteOperation.finish(WriteOperation.java:100)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.common.worker.MapTaskExecutor.execute(MapTaskExecutor.java:77)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.DataflowWorker.executeWork(DataflowWorker.java:254)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.DataflowWorker.doWork(DataflowWorker.java:191)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.DataflowWorker.getAndPerformWork(DataflowWorker.java:144)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.DataflowWorkerHarness$WorkerThread.doWork(DataflowWorkerHarness.java:180)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.DataflowWorkerHarness$WorkerThread.call(DataflowWorkerHarness.java:161)
    at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.DataflowWorkerHarness$WorkerThread.call(DataflowWorkerHarness.java:148)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Pipe broken
    at java.io.PipedInputStream.read(PipedInputStream.java:321)
    at java.io.PipedInputStream.read(PipedInputStream.java:377)
    at com.google.api.client.util.ByteStreams.read(ByteStreams.java:181)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.media.MediaHttpUploader.setContentAndHeadersOnCurrentRequest(MediaHttpUploader.java:629)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.media.MediaHttpUploader.resumableUpload(MediaHttpUploader.java:409)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.media.MediaHttpUploader.upload(MediaHttpUploader.java:336)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:427)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:352)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:469)
    at com.google.cloud.hadoop.util.AbstractGoogleAsyncWriteChannel$UploadOperation.call(AbstractGoogleAsyncWriteChannel.java:357)
    ... 4 more
```

This error is sometimes normal but batch job finally finish but now it is not finishing and failing in the middle after couple of hours.

I am kinda blocked with this error and not sure how to proceed and get our batch loader start again.

Comment: What is the job ID?

Comment: @jkff thanks for the response these are the few jobIds I tried
2016-12-29_12_29_45-1148799671021575971,
2016-12-27_13_15_06-5770071057185164024,
2016-12-28_01_43_39-6724563055033327735

Comment: Thanks, I've opened an internal ticket to investigate the Cloud Storage issues and I'll keep you updated.

Comment: @jkff do you have some update on the ticket or is there a way for me to follow the ticket ?

Comment: People are still investigating - nothing conclusive yet unfortunately.

Comment: Hmm. I noticed that you are using a very old Dataflow SDK (1.4 - over a year old), which also uses a very old Google Cloud Storage client library (also over a year old). It is possible that there are some bugs in the client that have been fixed since then. Can you try updating the SDK to a newer version and see if the problem persists?

Comment: @jkff updated the dataflow version to use 1.9.0 and started the new job 
jobId : 2017-01-05_14_02_15-11347734328069664728

Comment: Side note: I'm observing the job and it explicitly sets num_workers to 300. There is not enough parallelism in the job to provide work for all 300 workers, so most of them are sitting there idle, but you are still charged for them. I would strongly recommend to enable autoscaling instead - it will automatically grow and shrink the workerpool size as appropriate.

Comment: To enable autoscaling, all you need to do is stop specifying num_workers.

Comment: @jkff thats what we used to have but at some point this cause some trouble before even scaling up (I don't remember exactly what it was) so I set the number to 300 and solved the issue. Anyways I'll try again removing that.

Comment: @jkff new job also failed but this time its a different error. I got OOM error  while ago which showed workers crashed before even autoscaling to 300 due to the high load, so I set the fixed number 300 and it solved the issue, I will try removing that again. But my job is still failing after upgrading to 1.9.0 dataflow.

Comment: Do you have an ID of a failed job? The one you quoted above is cancelled.

Comment: this is the Id which failed : 2017-01-05_18_12_47-8525666819411572087

Comment: @jkff my last job (2017-01-06_12_28_50-6709364338548849152) ran for 1day and 16 hr and failed, usually our batch job finish in 8 hrs.

Comment: @jkff do you have some update on this issue ?

Comment: We're still looking and haven't found the issue - sorry to keep you waiting. In general, does this happen with all your pipelines, or only with this particular type of pipeline? If you have any other clues or patterns you noticed, that'd be very helpful too - e.g. does it tend to happen more at higher scale?

Comment: This is definitely something to do with the scale of the job because we have other environments running the same piece of code just fine, but not the production pipeline. If something else come up I will post.

Comment: One more thing. It seems that your code has something like "try {...c.output()...} catch {log something about unexpected error while analyzing bundle, and continue}" - this causes the write errors to be ignored until the very end of every (very long) bundle, so the job fails much later than it could have, i.e. it wastes more resources while doing that. Can you try pulling c.output() outside the try/catch? Worst case, it will cause the job to spend fewer resources; best case, it might even fix it if the errors are transient. (I'm still looking into why error happen at all)

Comment: One other thing I notice, the job seems extremely GC-heavy (and there's a log message about CoGbk result being more than 10000 elements, which switches to a slower codepath). That could conceivably cause networking issues too.

Comment: I think it may make sense to transfer the further debugging of this issue to dataflow-feedback@google.com. Could you write there? Maybe we can come up with some advice on making the job less heavy, if that's what's causing the issues.

Comment: @jkff Thanks for suggestions I found 5 places we are wrapping context.output and I am about to run removing them. I did not understand the issue with CoGbk and where is this logic to route to slower path. I definitely see a very big performance issue in CoGbk step because I used to see 400+ elements per seconds processed in previous batch runs but recent job is like some where around 10-20 elements per seconds. Can you please explain me bit more about this ?

Comment: @jkff I think I found where there's a limit for 10k elements. Is it possible to increase it ?

Comment: @jkff I checked the dataflow code and it seems I see we are exceeding the limit. I see whole bunch of error saying  "CoGbkResult has more than 10000 elements, reiteration (which may be slow) is required.". Do you have suggestions how to mitigate this error ?

Answer (score 2):

Posting an answer to address the last question on the comment thread above.

The message `"CoGbkResult has more than 10000 elements, reiteration (which may be slow) is required"` [is not an error](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowJavaSDK/blob/master/sdk/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/dataflow/sdk/transforms/join/CoGbkResult.java#L114). 10000 elements is chosen as the maximum amount to keep in memory at once, and it's just letting you know that it must re-iterate on the remaining results if you have more than 10000 of them.

I'd advise to continue debugging the issue on **dataflow-feedback@google.com** as [jkff](https://stackoverflow.com/users/278042/jkff) suggested rather than in the comment thread, since it's grown outside the scope of a Stack Overflow question.